# How to be certain when the page load is complete to measure load time

Tags: ruby, watir, page-load-time

I need to measure load time on a page navigation. Here is my situation:
When I navigate, the page laod is taking variable time as the ajax elements load. How to be certain that the page is fully loaded to measure its load time correctly? 
I cannot be specific that locating a particular element(text, table, or image...) indicate the complete page load as page load depends on data. 
Please help me deal with this situation.

Thanks

Comment: you can put `Time.now` before and after your suspected lines,and print that.Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to be able to test this on an "as needed" basis or do you want to instrument the pages so that you gather data from all your users?

If you just need to do it on an ad-hoc basis then http://webpagetest.org will help you - providing there's not too long a gap between the AJAX requests it will include them.

If you want to look gather data across all AJAX calls then you will need to instrument the success and failure callbacks to store the time they finish and calculate the difference between the last one and the page start. Then once you've got this push the value to Google Analytics or something else.

If all your AJAX calls are designed to complete before onload fires then the existing SiteSpeed numbers in Google Analytics might be good enough for you.